# Operator overloading in c (not c++) is it possible?

Tags: c++, c

This question arises from my need to "convert" std::string to char* form.

Preferably I would like to maintain as much code as possible and that includes plenty of "=" initialization/assignment operators.

standard c operators exist for the basic data types (int, char, float, pointers to, etc...).

Is it even possible to overload the assignment operator in c? I suppose that each data type as it's own operator so messing with one wouldn't mess with others.

Anyhow, this is just something that intrigued me as I can't find much references on how C operators are implemented.

Cheers

well, some examples are in order

```
std::string a_string;
a_string = "bla"
```

or using standard C

```
char a_char_array[10];
strcpy(a_char_array,"bla");
```

or

```
char *a_char_pointer = "bla";
```

what I'm thinking about is a wa to replace these 3 use cases with a single one where I can (through a #define) switch between using char* or std::string.

I guess that everyone that really cares about performance vs coding speed has already thought about the implications of using std::string instead of char*. All of the advantages of using stl are usually often offseted (is this even a word!?) by lower performance (you can't always get what you want right??).

As I said, I have a large project and I want to see for myself what are the changes in using one method or the other.

My post title was purposely misleading as I didn't want this to become a char* vs string battle, but I guess I can't really explain what I want without some more details.

Cheers

Comment: @Andre:Why can't you use c_str() of string?

Comment: @user. I can use it. I just don't want to ;) Lazy me I know! I am thinking about ways (probably using macros) to switch from std::string to char* and my only problem is the = operator. All the rest can be dealt with.

Comment: @Andre: It doesn't exist and I think that's a really bad idea. `char*` and `std::string` have very different semantics and I highly doubt that one can write a code that behaves **exactly the same** with one or the other.

Comment: @Andre:Your problem is how to "assign" the value of a string to a C-string?

Comment: Your code is C++, not C, if you use `std::string` type, which has namespace (absent in C) and the type is from C++'s STL <string> header.

Comment: @ereOn I know that. And the idea isn't a pick and replace std::string with char*.  As I said I have a very large codebase already. I want to do some (kind of) performance evaluation and I'm looking into simple (sic) ways to switch from one implementation to the other.

@user - no, not really

@Pawel - I know, this is a more advanced question then it seems

Comment: @Andre: maybe you should post a short bit of example code showing what you'd like to be able to do.

Comment: @Andre:To be honest I can not understand at all, what you are trying to do or what is your problem exactly

Comment: "I guess that everyone that really cares about performance vs coding speed has already thought about the implications of using std::string instead of char*. All of the advantages of using stl are usually often offset [...] by lower performance" BS. Everyone who cares about performance and knows what they are doing will __measure__ to find out where performance is lost -- and it's unlikely that STL vs. hand-written algorithms will gain much besides code obfuscation. `-1` from me for attempting to prematurely optimize something that isn't broken.

Comment: well.. probably this isn't premature because I already have a running project that I want to optimize, better yet, I want to know if using std::string instead of char* is really worth it.

Comment: @Andre: So __measure__ where it spends its time. Until you measured, it _is_ premature.

Comment: @sbi, this is a discussion that I don't want to go into. I want to do it and I'm looking into ways to do it. I'm not looking into something comprehensive and I just want to have a real idea of the difference  . I want to optimize this project because it's bit and I use std::string extensively in it. This isn't a I want to optimize because we need to optimize it scenario. I want to optimize it because I want to know what the difference will be at the end.

Comment: @Andre: So be it. `<shrug>` But if you come here telling us you want to obfuscate a piece of code in the name of performance without even measuring whether this peice of code even matters, you will have to live with people pointing out to you that what you're doing is stupid.

Comment: @sbi - this isn't for a public release or anything of that sort. I just want to have an idea. I use std::string everywhere in my code and I'm just left wondering "what if". It is clear to me that my code would be faster. But by how much? Is it really noticeable? Should I start using one instead of the other?

Comment: @Andre: The "what if" is answered easy enough: _If_ you don't use `std::string`, but use manual memory management, _then_ you will have to fight a constant battle against leaks, double deletes, and off-by-one errors. BTDT (and _nobody_ asks about performance when the durn things crashes all the time). And if you want to automate that, you will end up with an inferior version of `std::string`. So what's your point?

Comment: @Andre: -1 for trying to do sth. you don't understand. You don't care if you code is C or C++, you are trying to use char * and std::string as if it was the same. I would suggest to learn C++ and about profiling first.

Comment: @sbi, I'm not looking to automate for "real" usage, but I do want to be able to check, change and see how it really affects everything. I am well aware of all the implications and that's why I'm asking here about a "quick and dirty" way. @Valentin. Be cool man. Did you read everything? I am not trying to use them as if they are the same ;)

Comment: Even after you do this, how do you know if you've gained any performance unless you've profiled your code anyway?

Comment: Yes I will need to profile it, but before doing that I'm looking into ways to change my code with the least work possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in C overloading of `=` is not possible, for a simple reason: it is well defined for (almost) all types.

You'd really have to distinguish between assignment and initialization. Whereas initialization of arrays is possible, assignment is not. If your strings are compile time determined, all is easy:

```
char copy[] = { "abcd" }; // initialization, ok
copy = "1234";            // assignment, error
```

A trick to overcome this problem is to encapsulate a string in a `struct`

```
typedef struct mystring mystring;
struct mystring { char a[24]; };

mystring a = { "abcd" };
mystring b = a;
mystring c = { 0 };
c = b;
```

This will do the right thing if you always care to initialize your variables as indicated above.

Answer (score 12):

If you see std::string in your code, and the compiler doesn't complain, then you have a C++, not C.

Comment: Well, I'm not a purist. I always compile with gcc and I don't care if I'm mixing C with C++. For what I am concerned they are the same language (and I don't want to go into any discussion about this, ok everyone? ;) ). This isn't an hello world project and I would go into details of how std::string is implemented, but what I want is a quick and dirty (probably with some sort of macros) way to use std::string or char*. I am aware of all of the implications and difficulties. That's why I'm asking here ;)

Comment: @Andre: "For what I am concerned they are the same language" - No, C++ and C are not the same language. Yes, they have similarities, but they are effectively different languages and things are done differently between the two. You cannot shoehorn proper C++ into C or proper C into C++ and expect it to work in a frictionless manner.

Comment: Hey silico, That is true, but there is much to gain from mixing both. I usually work with low end systems where every bit of performance and binary size gained is a plus. I use C++ because it makes my coding simpler and more productive, but in the end I know that when I use stl I am using way more then I need. This balance between C and C++ is very important for me and I mix both whenever I need to. We must follow rules, but for me working with C and C++ is the same ;). I just need to know (and be sure about) what I am doing, and if I don't know... well I'd better learn ;)

Comment: @Andre: How tired I am from hearing this :-(. Performance-explanations are the last resort of bad software developer.  If you've just started using C/C++ (less then 1 year), there is a hope indeed that you'll learn.

Comment: @Valentin, but, what is the problem of knowing how stuff really works and understand their implications? After all isn't that the way we all learn?

Comment: @Andre: you can define the C language any way you like, but in order to communicate with *other* developers, it helps if you use the same definitions as everyone else. And to the rest of us, C and C++ are different languages. `std::string` (or indeed, anything using the `std` namespace or any other namespace) are only available in C++. Operator overloading is only available in C++. Explicitly asking a question about C, and then mixing in C++ features and C++ sample code just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6):

C does not allow any kind of overloading, operators are built-in (direct translation to assembly code).

There may be some possible tricks using macros depending of your actual code base, but I would discourage it anyway. It is likely to introduce bugs. Just go with plain functions.

Comment: I was thinking about Macros, but my "problem" is replacing everywhere where I have std::string::=

Comment: assignment to str::string implies hidden memory allocation, hence any solution will need to perform memory allocation, to copy data, then when it is not needed any more to free memory (as you can't rely any more on automatic C++ objects going out of scope). It looks like a dangerous change. Are you **really, really, really** needing to do that...

Comment: no, not really. I just want to know what will be the performance difference between the two. I am aware of the internal mechanism, and I know that I will have to (one way or another) allocate memory for all the char* I have. of all of the stl, std::string seems to be the one where we have less to gain. On one side we have easy code that manages memory for itself. On the other hand we have a fairly complicated class for something that is very simple and in most cases doesn't need to be changed very often (in which case std::string is probably better). I'm just looking for some extra insight.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot overload operators in C, you need to explicitly call a function to do the conversion. The compiler will only do some conversions for you (ints <-> floats, some pointer stuff, etc), but never more intricate stuff.

Comment: A good reference on operators - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B 
I supposed that much but needed some references on it.

Answer (score -1):

FYI: LccWin32 has some extensions that allow for operator overloading